# docker image directory does not exist during build

Tags: linux, docker

I'm building a simple image from a Dockerfile: (note, `pm3` is the name of the folder this Dockerfile lives in)

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda3
MINTAINER Jordan Miller
ENV PORT=5000
COPY .  /opt/repos/
WORKDIR /opt/repos/pm3/

RUN ls -la

RUN python /opt/repos/pm3/lib/acquire_requirements.py

EXPOSE $PORT
ENTRYPOINT ["python","/opt/repos/pm3/src/web/api.py"]
```

I use `docker build -f Dockerfile -t jm/pm3 .` to build it. Now I thought this was working great last week, but I made some changes and it broke. so I ran `docker system prune` to clean everything out. But that didn't fix it so I think it's something wrong with the code.

At any rate, here's the error I get:

```
Step 7/9 : RUN python /opt/repos/pm3/lib/acquire_requirements.py
 ---> Running in f842a282a6a0
Invalid requirement: '/opt/repos/pm3/lib/acquire_requirements.py'
 File '/opt/repos/pm3/lib/acquire_requirements.py' does not exist.
```

But it really is there, in my windows machine there's a `lib` folder in the `pm3` folder and there is a `acquire_requirements.py` in the `lib` folder. should I not include the entire path to it on the linux box or something?

I included that line `RUN ls -la` after it gave me the error because I wanted to see if it copied over the folder correctly. but the output of that didn't show me anything had copied over, it showed an empty file. so I don't understand really what's going on. If the working directory really is `/opt/repos/pm3` then shouldn't I see `src` when I run `ls`?

I'm hoping there's something obvious about linux or docker that I'm missing here. any ideas?

Comment: Do you have `.dockerignore` file? Also, you are running `docker build` in the same directory as the Dockerfile right? Can you update with the contents of the `pm3` directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I discovered by creating an image without the `RUN python /opt/repos/pm3/lib/acquire_requirements.py` that it doens't create a folder after the `/opt/repos/` called `pm3` like my root directory of the Dockerfile is in.

So I had to add that in manually to the command:

`COPY .  /opt/repos/` -> `COPY .  /opt/repos/pm3/`